# Geting data from php with json and puting in a fancybox

Tags: php, jquery, json

Well i'm trying to get some error messages of my fileupload.
i'm trying to get the error messages from php and puting in a json, after geting json in other page, i'm in this step because json_decode don't works in my atual code, someone can help?

form-action.php:

```
if( @move_uploaded_file( $file_tmp, $destiny  ))
        {
            $message = "sucess";
        }
        else
            $message = "Error 1";
    }
    else
        $message = "you can send only \"*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.png\"<br />";
}
else
{
    $message = "you dont send any files!";
}
```

form.php: (trying to get json here)
in this echo show "Json dont works!"

```
<?php
  if(isset($_GET['data'])){

   $myjson = json_decode($_GET['data']);
}
    else{

     $myjson = 'Json dont works!'; // o json não foi passado
}
    echo $myjson;
?>
```

Comment: Why not wrap it in a try catch and handle the exception?

Comment: `json_decode` doesn't throw an exception. "In the event of a failure to decode, `json_last_error()` can be used to determine the exact nature of the error." http://php.net/json_decode